# While importing tensorflow I got an "errror" saying the following

Tags: tensorflow

> 2019-11-07 00:41:30.414603: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll

Is this an error or is it normal? I saw 'successfully' so I'm thinking its good but is it?

Comment: Well, does it state anything that looks like an error?

Comment: Not as I know of but id there anyway I can test it? because i'm new to tensorflow and willing to learn but I dont wanna have to redownload the whole thing while following a tutorial.

Comment: Literally all it says that it successfully opened a library (related to CUDA, needed for GPU support). No reason to worry.